# Nativescript action bar across views

Tags: nativescript-angular

I have a app.html file that has this code.

```
    <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"  actionBarHidden="true">
    <ActionBar title="Tooling U-SME" class="action-bar" height="50">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"
      ios:horizontalAlignment="center"
      android:horizontalAlignment="center">
      <Image src="res://tulogo" stretch="none"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</Page>
```

The action bar appears ok on my root default page with the proper page-router-outlet, but when the outlet changes the action bar does not appear. Instead a kind of default action bar appears. How do I have an action bar common to all my page views?

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the basics in NativeScript Angular? There are few core differences in declaring your components in HTML vs XML (Core NativeScript)

You suppose to not declare `Page` element, `page-router-outlet` actually does that for you. Try to declare action bar in your components which you are going to load inside `page-router-outlet`.

Comment: I did do the tutorials. I hadn't read that you had to include the action bar in the components within the router. I tried and that didn't work either. I did remove the Page element from my app.component.html and it doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: If you understood what is a Page and where ActionBar comes from, ActionBar is a member of Page so when new Page is created by page-router-outlet, you may not have the old ActionBar defined for previous page. Try checking the starter template in market place so you will have some idea how to start.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I finally figured out what was the issue. I didn't import NativeScriptCommonModule

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post I figured it out:

https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-angular-modules-in-nativescript-apps

I hadn't imported NativeScriptCommonModule in my Feature Module.